# This program can read single wav for MFCC feature extraction, i need program that can read multiple wav and gives MFCC features

Tags: python, numpy

This program can read single wav for MFCC feature extraction, i need program that can read multiple wav and gives MFCC features

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
from python_speech_features import delta
from python_speech_features import logfbank
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

(rate,sig) = wav.read("67_P.wav")
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
d_mfcc_feat = delta(mfcc_feat, 2)
fbank_feat = logfbank(sig,rate)

print(fbank_feat[1:3,:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you want but I am guessing you need something like this.

Assuming the folder name that you have stored the .wav files is "data",

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
from python_speech_features import delta
from python_speech_features import logfbank
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import os

data_path = "data/"

for filename in os.listdir(data_path):
    (rate,sig) = wav.read(data_path + filename)
    mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
    d_mfcc_feat = delta(mfcc_feat, 2)
    fbank_feat = logfbank(sig,rate)
    print filename
    print(fbank_feat[1:3,:])
```

This will read all the .wav files inside the data folder one by one and extract the features you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
for filename in os.listdir(directoryName):
    if filename.endswith('.wav'): # only get MFCCs from .wavs
        # read in our file
        (rate,sig) = wav.read(directoryName + "/" +filename)
        # get mfcc
        mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)
        # get filterbank energies
        fbank_feat = logfbank(sig,rate)
        # create a file to save our results in
        
        outputFile = resultsDirectory + "/" + "op.csv"
        file = open(outputFile, 'a+') 
        
        numpy.savetxt(file, fbank_feat, delimiter=",") #save MFCCs as .csv
        file.close()
```

**This code will not create separate csv file for each .wav file.**